# Filtro e execução em Shell Script

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script

Estou com um problema em **Shell Script**, onde:

- Precisa informar um arquivo;
- Verificar se é um arquivo **.C**, **.JAVA** ou nenhum dos dois;
- Caso seja algum dos dois, compilar conforme o escolhido e executar;

**(Não entendo muito de Shell e fiquei com essa dúvida)**

```
#!/bin/sh

dialog --backtitle "Código FOnte" --title "Menu" --menu "Selecione " 0 0 6 \
  1 "Exibir status das utilizações das partições" \
  2 "Relação de usuários logados " \
  3 "Informe um arquivo e receba sua informação em bytes " \
  4 "Passe um programa em C ou java e execute " 2>/tmp/menuitem.$$
  menuitem=`cat /tmp/menuitem.$$`

  opt=$?

 case $menuitem in
  1) df -h > /tmp/item.1 && dialog --textbox /tmp/item.1 20 80  ;;
  2) who > /tmp/item.2 && dialog --textbox /tmp/item.2 20 80  ;;
  3) dialog --inputbox 'Digite caminho e o arquivo :' 0 0  2>/tmp/nome.txt
     caminho=$( cat /tmp/nome.txt )
     arquivo=$( ls -lh $caminho | awk '{print $9 "------------------------------------->" $5}') ;;
  4) ;;
esac
```

Comment: O que vc deseja? criar um arquivo Shell Script? vc não tem nenhum código de exemplo?

Comment: Sim, desejo criar um arquivo em Shell Script

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar a extensão do arquivo baseado em seus últimos caracteres, como no exemplo abaixo onde verifico os 4 ultimos:

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "qual o arquivo?"
read arquivo

if [ ${arquivo: -4} == ".txt" ]; then
    echo "arquivo tipo txt"
elif [ ${arquivo: -4} == ".doc" ]; then
    echo "arquivo tipo doc"
else
    echo "arquivo invalido"
fi
```

Comment: Ele informa : **Bad substitution**

Comment: Onde exatamente ele apresentou este erro? Cole seu código adaptado aqui para análise, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Eu sigo a resposta anterior, só acrescento algumas coisas a mais:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "qual o arquivo?"
read arquivo

# testa se é um arquivo regular    
if [ ! -f "${arquivo}" ] ; then
   echo "${arquivo}" não encontrado
   exit 1
fi


# método1: obtenção da extensão diretamente na atribuição de variável
extensao=${arquivo##*.}

# se não funcionar no teu shell, utilize este outro código
# método2: obtenção da extensão com ajuda do awk
# extensao=`echo ${arquivo} | awk -F "." '{print $NF;}'`

# conversão para minuscula
extensao=`echo "${extensao}" | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'`

# tratamento do arquivo
if [ "${extensao}" == "c" ]; then
    echo "arquivo C"
    # rode um teste de compilação C
elif [ "${extensao}" == "java" ]; then
    echo "arquivo java"
    # rode um teste de compilação java
else
    echo "arquivo invalido"
fi
```

Observe que é interessante normalizar o case das extensões para não ter de testar maiúsculo e minúsculo. O que pode ter dado o erro é que comandos como esse `${arquivo: -4}` não serem suportados no shell `/bin/sh`, aí tem uma outra opção de fazer em [awk](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AWK) (comando comentado).

O comando [dialog (ou whiptail no debian)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) é interessante para gerar diálogos (menus, perguntas tipo sim-não, etc) mas acho também desnecessário para o problema.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando @gwarah!!
  Mas estou com uma dificuldade para fazer executar o programa, onde caso ele for um código em **C**, ele precisa compilar e executar o mesmo. Deveria ficar como?

Exemplo:

`if [ "${extensao}" == "c" ]; then
  gcc $arquivo -o prog   #Compilar
  ./prog #Executar
               #Mostrar`

Comment: C não é a minha praia @Luiz, já faz um tempo que não programo, mas acho que é esta a sintaxe mesmo. Será que não é alguma coisa  no conteúdo do arquivo que está quebrando? Posta a saída de erro.

Comment: Na verdade ele não mostra saída, ele apenas fica parado sem realizar nenhuma operação!

Comment: Antes de executar o `gcc`, coloca um `echo sinal 1` e depois do `gcc` um `echo sinal 2` e depois do ./prog, `echo sinal 3`. Fiz uma alteração no programa para testar se o `${arquivo}` existe no mesmo diretório do programa. Faz estas alterações e posta o resultado.